# Errors in logistic regression using caret R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, r-caret

I am using caret in R to construct several models for classification. I would like to use logistic regression for this purpose, but I keep getting failures in the models. Here is my call to logistic regression and the output:

```
train_control = trainControl(method='cv', number = 7, allowParallel = TRUE)
glm_model = caret::train(label ~., data=xtrain, method='glm',
                         family=binomial(link='logit'),
                         verbose=TRUE, trControl=train_control)

Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :1     NA's   :1   
Error: Stopping
In addition: Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

I've had this happen several times, and occasionally it will work, but often I get this result. I've also tried using the "plr" method with the same result. What's odd about this is that I can use the "glm" call from R directly and it works.

```
glm_model = glm(label ~., family=binomial(link='logit'), data=xtrain)

Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

What am I doing wrong with caret?

Comment: Hi @CopyOfA, it seems like you have complete separation https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-complete-or-quasi-complete-separation-in-logisticprobit-regression-and-how-do-we-deal-with-them/ or so called Hauck-donner effect but caret should still work

Comment: can you do dput(head(xtrain,20)) and paste the output? I suspect something is weird in your data

Comment: The other possibility is that since you allowed parallelization, that did not work for some reason. Try to set ```allowParallel = FALSE``` and see

Comment: Regarding your third comment, I have tried with and without `allowParallel`, and there's no change. I suspect you're correct in that there is complete separation, which is why I get the warning messages from `glm(label ~., family=binomial(link='logit'), data=xtrain)`. However, there is something about `caret` that causes it to fail when it reaches this point. I'm not sure that I can put data here, since it is relatively large (~130 features plus the labels). Is there a way to test for this? I am also using caret to train a random forest and MLP and neither of them fail.

Comment: I honestly cannot tell where it went wrong. I tried on an example dataset which as some hauck-donner and caret works just fine on it